# Multi-class classification using LIBLINEAR

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, liblinear

I am a beginner to SVM which i have successfully implemented one-class classification.Now i want to know about multi-class classification which am very much confused about.

I went through  [How to do multi class classification using Support Vector Machines (SVM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958267/how-to-do-multi-class-classification-using-support-vector-machines-svm) which i want the exact same output but the link does not have a specific example using windows.If anyone can help me out with an example in windows for both  “ONE-AGAINST-ONE”,”ONE-AGAINST-ALL” methods of multi-class classification

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using libLinear you will not be able to have a similar output because it cannot predict probabilities. You should use libSVM for that.

LibLinear does not support multi-class classification by default, but you can download [this tool from the official site](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#liblinear_for_one_versus_one_multi_class_classification) and it can do the job.

If you want multi-class probability estimate, [you can take a look at this tool](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/#multi_class_classification_and_probability_output_via_error_correcting_codes)

Comment: thanks for the answer.I tried using train -s0 and then predict -b 1 and it gives me probabilty for all the classes.Does this mean multi-class classification?

Comment: Well if it produces the output you expected, I would say yes.

Comment: thank you very much.It saved my day.I have same question but in other format.have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685255/multi-label-prediction-using-liblinear.if possible please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answer is talking about multi-label classification or something because liblinear does support multi-class classification by default (Choose -s to be between 0 and 7, there are 8 different modes https://github.com/cjlin1/liblinear/blob/master/README)

For the input, you can use the same as binary classification, but just set the label to be the index of the class (between 0 and (# of classes - 1)) instead of ±1.