# Multi-label prediction using LIBLINEAR

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm, liblinear

I am using LIBLINEAR and i need to know whether Multi-Label Prediction in windows is possible or not.I tried google but no luck

I want the output to be produced the following way

I train some 10 documents with three class labels 1,2,3 and now when i feed a test document to the classifier and if the document belongs to label 1 and 2 then it should produce 1,2 or something else which shows that document belongs to 1 and 2 both the class labels

I want an example in windows

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multi-class classification using LIBLINEAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24639325/multi-class-classification-using-liblinear)

Answer (score 0):

By default neither libSvm nor LibLinear supports multiclass classification.

You need to perform a **One against all** approach.

You can find help on [the libsvm page which provides different tools for multi-label classification that are based on LIBSVM or LIBLINEAR](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/multilabel/)

Comment: thank you..I did gone through the above link but it does not have any example in windows.I need example in widows

Comment: yeah but in which programming language?

Comment: c or c++.The same language in which libsvm or liblinear is compiled for windows version